# when i am hiiting the application using web server, iam getting this error "File does not exist: /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/maximo"

Tags: websphere, maximo, ibmhttpserver

when i am hiiting the application using web server, iam getting this error "File does not exist: /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/maximo" but another working with same configuration. every thing is right but still getting this error

Answer (score 3):

The direct cause of this is that the WAS WebServer Plugin did not handle the request, nor did any other Apache module, so the core of Apache tries to serve the path out of the filesystem.  But it's meant to be served by some application server.

The next step is why the WAS Plugin declines the request?  The plugin-cfg.xml knows which context roots and backend virtual hosts your application is mapped to.

Maximo users often mysteriously feel the need to map the Maximo application to a custom WebSphere virtual host (aka maximo_host).  If you do this, maximo_host must have the hostname (or wildcard) and ports **as used by the client**, not just backend application server listening ports.  This would usually be port 443.

Of course this has to be correct not just in the WAS configuration but in the plugin-cfg.xml generated/propagated from it.